# Resetting position using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, reset

I have this code in CSS:

```
#blueToken
{
    top:415px;
    left:35px;
    z-index: 80;
}

#redToken
{
    top:405px;
    left:25px; 
    z-index: 70;
}
```

After finishing one game, one token is on the "finish line" and the other one can be anywhere on the screen.
I want to reset both positions once I click a button. (I'm using JS with jQuery).

Comment: Please post your jQuery code so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the starting position is same as the CSS code and you have a button with a class name `btn-reset` to reset the position.

```
$('.btn-reset').click(function() {
   $('#blueToken').css({
       top: 415,
       left: 35,
       'z-index': 80
   });
   $('#redToken').css({
       top: 415,
       left: 25,
       'z-index': 70
   });
});
```

Comment: Note that it should be written like this :
`$('#blueToken').css({
       top: 415,
       left: 35,
       'z-index': 80
   });`
(without the semicolons in the css class, otherwise it doesn't work)
It does what I needed, thanks a lot!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You should use `position property` with `top, left or z-index property`

Also use class for this,like

```
.blueToken
{
    top:415px;
    left:35px;
    z-index: 80;
    position:relative;
}

.redToken
{
    top:405px;
    left:25px; 
    z-index: 70;
    position:relative;
}
```

And use [jquery.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) for `add or remove class`.

This `code` may help you,

```
$('.btn-reset').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('blueToken redToken');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I really don't want to touch the css code, as I didn't do it. I will try to understand the toggleClass later on, but for now I'll use `.css()`. Thanks again! :)